# SharePoint migration planning

Tags: migration

I am planning for a migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Server 2010 and am seeking clarifiication on a couple of points.

i) Does SharePoint have to be loaded onto every server in a server farm.
ii) Are the backups of the content databases restored to the SQL Server before being being attached
iii) Is the SharePoint Management Shell on the application server or the SQl Server in the farm ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to install SharePoint on the SQL or Email servers
2. Yes, restore your backups to the new SQL server before attaching them to SP
3. Application server